# Referencing an Email In A Sub From A Specific range

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using the below as part of a macro to email some pivot data to a list of customers. but at the moment it only goes to one email address. I tried amending it to look in a specific range for the hyperlink and it errors and wont send the email. In the range J1 I also have a Vlookup formula running to match the ac and email address. Any help would be great.

```
Receiver = Sheets ("Pivot").Select Range("J1").value 'it errors on this line           
Topic = "Backorder overview" 
Attachment = strFilename
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the use of `.Select`. See this

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Change the line

```
Receiver = Sheets ("Pivot").Select Range("J1").value
```

to

```
Receiver = Sheets("Pivot").Range("J1").value
```